# Value $\Phi_n(1)$ of the cyclotomic polynomial at x=1

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Value of cyclotomic polynomial evaluated at 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49956/value-of-cyclotomic-polynomial-evaluated-at-1)

I have to show $\Phi_n(1)=1$ for $n\neq p^k$ with $p$ is prime. 
(I already proved to easy part $\Phi_n(1)=p$ for $n=p^k$)

For the proof I would start with:
For an arbitrary natural number $n$ we have the unique factorization of primes $n=p_1^{\beta_1}p_2^{\beta_2}\cdots p_k^{\beta_k}$ ($gcd(p_i,p_j)=1$ for $i\neq j$)

I know that there are $\beta_i$ divisors of $n$, which are the powers of each prime $p_i$ which divide $n$.
But how can I say that $\Phi_d(1)=1$ for any $d$ with more than one prime divisor?

Comment: start with what you know, like perhaps $$x^n-1=\prod_{0<d|n}\Phi_d(x)$$ and $$\Phi_d(x)=\prod_{0<d|n}\left(x^d-1\right)^{\mu(n/d)}=\prod_{(d,n)=1}\left(x-e^{2\pi id/n}\right)$$

Comment: Given your factorization of $n$, there are [$\tau(n)=\prod(\beta_i+1)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) divisors of $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: For $n>1$,
$$\Phi_n(x)=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k}{\prod_{1 < d < n,~d|n}\Phi_d(x)}$$
is the ratio of $\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$
to the product of $\Phi_d(x)$
over all proper divisors $d$ of $n$.
The numerator is just $n$ when $x=1$
(which also follows from L'Hôpital's rule for the limit of the ratio as $x\to1$),
and the denominator gives you
an inductive statement about
$$a_n=\begin{cases}1,&n=1;\\\Phi_n(1),&n>1,\end{cases}$$
namely
$$
a_1=1,\quad
a_n=\frac{n}{\prod_{1<d<n,~d|n}a_d}
$$
where, again, the product is over all proper divisors $d$ of $n$.
For example the result that $a_n=p$ for $n=p^k$ a
positive power of a prime follows by an easy induction.

For the general case, write $a(n)=\Phi_n(1)+\epsilon(n)$, as a function, where
$\epsilon(n)=\delta_{1n}$ is $1$ for $n=1$ and $0$ for $n\ne1$.
Then $a$ is an [arithmetic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function), in fact a unit,
and $\epsilon$ is the multiplicative identity,
in the [Dirichlet ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution#Properties) of such functions,
and we have the identity $n=\prod_{0<d|n}a(n)$
(i.e., $\log(n)=\log(a(n))*1$ using
Dirichlet convolution and natural logarithms).
This has solution given by the Möbius inversion formula, which states that $f=g*1\iff g=f*\mu$ for arithmetic functions $f,g$:
$$
\log(a(n))
=\sum_{0<d|n}\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\log d
=\Lambda(n),
$$
where $\Lambda(n)$ is the [von Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function), so
\begin{align}
a(n)&
=\prod_{0<d|n}\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\log d
=e^{\Lambda(n)}\\
&=n^{\epsilon(\omega(n))/\Omega(n)}
=\begin{cases}p&\text{if }n=p^k\text{ is a power of a single prime};
\\1&\text{otherwise, i.e. if }n=1\text{ or }\omega(n)>1,\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $\omega(n)$ and $\Omega(n)$ are the [prime omega functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function), so that
$$
\Phi_n(1)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if }n=1;\\
p&\text{if }n=p^k;\\
1&\omega(n)>1.\end{cases}
$$

*EDIT*:

Further proofs and discussion can be found in Naslund's and [Bontea's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49956/value-of-cyclotomic-polynomial-evaluated-at-1/137777#137777) solutions in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49956/value-of-cyclotomic-polynomial-evaluated-at-1) of the identical question!